# Print sets of lines from multiple folders as rows, not columns?

Tags: unix, awk

I have .out files in multiple folders.

Let's say I am in a directory containing folders A, B, C, D. I use the command below to print a specific value from the 8th column of lines containing the keyword VALUE in all .out files in folders A, B, C, D

```
awk '/VALUE/{print $8}' ./*/.out
```

My result would look like:

```
output1_A
output2_A
output3_A

output1_B
output2_B
output3_B

output1_C
output2_C
output3_C
```

Is there a way I could get my output to look like what is shown below instead?

```
output1_A output2_A output3_A 
output1_B output2_B output3_B 
output1_C output2_C output3_C
```

In other words, have a space separate outputs from the same folder, and not a linebreak?

Comment: The outputs are just numbers that are part of a column. For example, from the line below, which is part of a larger .out file, the printed output would be 14566.5 

`VALUE  1:  B=   0.4320 a      1.806 b    14566.5 c`

Comment: `My result would look like:` - no, it wouldn't. Those blank lines wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(since I don't have directory structure so I couldn't test it or if OP could post file's contents inside directory perhaps we could do in single `awk` itself too).

```
awk '/VALUE/{print $8}' ./*/.out | xargs -n 3
```

Comment: That would only work if `VALUE` always existed in exactly 1 line in every input file in directories A, B, and C and never existed in the files in directory D. Hard to imagine that's what the OP has since if it were then why even look in the files in `D`? I know it's the accepted answer but I wonder if the OP has really thought this through and/or tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$ awk '/VALUE/{b=b (FNR==(NR>FNR)?ORS:ofs) $8;ofs=OFS}END{print b}' dir?/file1
output1_A output2_A output3_A
output1_B output2_B output3_B
output1_C output2_C output3_C
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/VALUE/ {                                # magic keyword
    b=b (FNR==(NR>FNR)?ORS:ofs) $8       # gathering a buffer set ORS or OFS appropriately
    ofs=OFS                              # ... but @NR==1 we want ""
}
END {
    print b                              # output buffer
}' dir?/file1
```

The unexplained two empty records in your sample are not considered but would probably cause extra `OFS`es in the ends of the output records.